# NodeJS Multer is not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, multer

I tried to file upload with NodeJS + ExpressJS + Multer but does not work well.

My ExpressJS Version is 4.12.3

this is my source

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    multer  = require('multer');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body); // form fields
    console.log(req.files); // form files
    res.status(204).end()
});
app.get('/', function(req, res)  {
    res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});

app.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log("start 5000");
});
```

public/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="file" type="file"/>
        <button type="submit">test</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My NodeJS Console Log when I click Submit Button:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" server.js
start 5000
{}
```

on NodeJS Console, there is empty object at req.files
Is some problem on my source?

Comment: Does the form actually hit the endpoint? `app.post('/', function(req, res)`?

Comment: Your file input doesn't have a `name` attribute, plus you still need `body-parser` for `req.body`.

Comment: @RichardMacarhy yeah. this is correct.

Comment: @BenFortune sorry, this is part of my source. I copied to my project for question. maybe my mistakes. whatever multer doesn't work well.

Comment: @DingGGu What I'm saying is inputs *require* a `name` attribute.

Comment: If this ever helps anyone: `multer` stopped working for me after upgrading it from 1.4.4 to 1.4.4-lts.1. The reason for this was that - in 1.4.4 (wrongly) allowed me post a file with `Content-type=application/json`. In 1.4.4-lts.1 they fixed this behavior and only `Content-type=multipart/form-data` works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't see you calling any API to upload file on click of submit button. Let me give you more comprehensive implementation.

### multer config in `app.js`

```
app.use(multer({ 
    dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + Date.now()
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' is starting ...')
    },
    onFileUploadData: function (file, data) {
        console.log(data.length + ' of ' + file.fieldname + ' arrived')
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
    }
}));
```

### View

```
<form id="uploadProfilePicForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/profile_pic_upload" method="post">
          <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="userPhotoInput" name="userPhoto"  accept="image/*" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**End point '`/user/profile_pic_upload`' POST calls `uploadProfilePic` in controller**

```
var control = require('../controllers/controller');
app.post('/user/profile_pic_upload',control.uploadProfilePic);
```

### Upload profile pic logic in users controller

```
uploadProfilePic = function(req,res){
    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmp_path = req.files.userPhoto.path;
    // set where the file should actually exists 
    var target_path = '/Users/narendra/Documents/Workspaces/NodeExpressWorkspace/MongoExpressUploads/profile_pic/' + req.files.userPhoto.name;
    // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }else{
                    var profile_pic = req.files.userPhoto.name;
                    //use profile_pic to do other stuffs like update DB or write rendering logic here.
             };
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: per documentation on readme https://github.com/expressjs/multer i don't believe any of these (outside of dest) are current multer options

Comment: @ lfender6445 Yeah you are right. I spend about an hour trying to figure out why the onFile* functions were not getting called.

Comment: It gives error: `app.use() requires a middleware function`

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Found solution. I am using `res` instead of `file` like `function(req, res,......)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        console.log(file);
        callback(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/', upload.single('photo'), function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body) // form fields
    console.log(req.file) // form files
    res.status(204).end()
});
```

ref: 
http://wiki.workassis.com/nodejs-express-get-post-multipart-request-handling-example/

Comment: this one worked best for me, thank you my hero

Comment: This kind of approach worked for me in localhost. In production, It is not working.